# PHP merge two arrays with matching values based on key

Tags: php

I have two arrays; the first one has a set of instructions to delete what post from the second array.

**The First Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_delete] => 1
            [post_key] => YXdsrP
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_delete] => 1
            [post_key] => 1jV37Q
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_delete] => 1
            [post_key] => JvlMIL
        )
)
```

**The Second Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 598490e010c7c25738677bd0
            [post_key] => TbjI1A
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 598490c210c7c24938677bd1
            [post_key] => YXdsrP
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 598490a41908cd2619677bd0
            [post_key] => myYIKh
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 59847e2a10c7c2155ff80e82
            [post_key] => 1jV37Q
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 59847e076bf29fec56f274c2
            [post_key] => JvlMIL
        )
)
```

I am looking to combine these two arrays and create one based on matching the keys labeled "post_key" within each array, while dropping the others from the second array. The end result I am looking for.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_delete] => 1
            [post_key] => YXdsrP
            [post_id] => 598490c210c7c24938677bd1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_delete] => 1
            [post_key] => 1jV37Q
            [post_id] => 59847e2a10c7c2155ff80e82
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [post_delete] => 1
            [post_key] => JvlMIL
            [post_id] => 59847e076bf29fec56f274c2
        )
)
```

Comment: So, what's your question? "Write the code for me"?

Comment: use array_column($array, null, 'post_key') on both arrays to reindex them by the post_key, array_intersect(array_keys($second_array),array_keys($first_array)) to get an array of keys that are in both arrays and loop on these keys to put elements into a new array.

Comment: It is more fun try for yourself. Go to [php.net](https://php.net), look at the function names to see if there are any ones interesting or related to what you want. Read their description, try them out, learn. Search on google. It is way faster than waiting for an answer here and you might find something you can adapt to your needs and discover related concepts, that will be helpful later. Search on this site and look for similar questions. If you really get stuck and need advice, then you should ask a question here. It's only an achievement if you work for it, and learn from it.